# Data loading for non-page components in SvelteKit

Tags: routes, svelte, loading, sveltekit

I am developing an application in SvelteKit where I multiple non-page components need to load data and I would like to do it similar to how +page.ts and +page.server.ts offer convenient and type safety. SvelteKit do not support parallel routes (i.e. layouts with multiple named slots) for me to use multiple pages (not that I am a fan of their routing coupling to project directory structure). How would you go about this problem, since not all data is needed on my single page load?

Comment: Hello.  I'm a bit confused.  Are you working a SvelteKit project, but it is a single page application?

Comment: Hi @JoséRamírez and thank you for passing by. I am using SvelteKit with SSR but my application consists of a single page where multiple components need to load data on their own in parallel. I would like to benefit from SvelteKit way of data loading for convenient and type safety.

Comment: I see.  I would say your case is not covered in SvelteKit's design.  I think you should just create a regular Vite + Svelte project instead, since I think SvelteKit will be in your way more than it will help.  I think your best bet is to settle for a traditional SPA.

Comment: You could try to Asynchronously load the svelte components like here https://svelte.dev/repl/079c14630f0a4c3785d7e83f58558075?version=3.16.5 . With that you could load the component on an event like a 'Tab' click.

Answer (score 0):

You can just import PageData from the page you want in the script tag of your component

Component

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from '../routes/teste/$types';
    export let data: PageData;

    const pageData = data.test;

    console.log(pageData);
    
</script>
```

src/routes/teste/+page.server.ts

```js
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load = (async () => {
    const test = 'testing';
    return {test};
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```